# PhpStorm: Unresolved pipe uppercase and unrecognized router-outlet

Tags: angular, pipe, phpstorm, webstorm

I got some problems with PhpStorm:

1. The pipe uppercase is unresolved and
2. `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is not recognised either.

What can be done about it? Maybe someone knows how to make this work in either PhpStorm or WebStorm?

Answer (score 2):

I installed the latest Early Access version of PhpStorm.
The regular version isn't compatible with Angular 13.